# Laravel - Foreach loop from a language file?

Tags: php, laravel

have a language file called "faq" which lists all the frequently asked questions and answers.

I have no idea how to do a foreach loop from those language files.

My faq.php language file:

```
return [
    'faq_1'       => 'Question here',
    'faq_1_ans'   => 'Answer here',
    'faq_2'       => 'Question here',
    'faq_2_ans'   => 'Answer here',
];
```

How can I make that into a foreach loop? I really don't know where to start.

Comment: That is a terrible structure for the faq array, could you edit that array or would you have to work with it as is?

Comment: I can change the structure. I've been getting faq from database all this time but now I decided to make it multi language .

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You might want to change the **structure**

```
return [
    'faq_1'       => [
        'q' => "Question",
        'a' => "Answer Here"
    ],
    'faq_2'       => [
        'q' => "Question",
        'a' => "Answer Here"
    ],
];
```

or even

```
return [
    [
        'q' => "Question",
        'a' => "Answer Here"
    ],
    [
        'q' => "Question",
        'a' => "Answer Here"
    ],
];
```

this way you can loop:

```
$faqs = Lang::get('faq');
foreach($faqs as $faq)
{
    echo "question: " . $faq['q'];
    echo "answer: " . $faq['a']:
}
```

Comment: That second example is the way to go

Answer (score 1):

Also you can use helper trans()

For example in blade template:

```html
@foreach(trans()->get('faq') as $key => $value)
  <select val="{{ $key }}">{{ $value }}</select>
@endforeach
```